# Regular expression to match single quotes, double quotes and/or space

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression looking for `width=["|\']([^"]*)["|\']`

works great when looking for `width="750"` and `width='750'` however it does not match `width=750`

so I got it as far as `width=["|\']?([^"]*)["|\']` for optional first quote but the match just continues on and does not return just `750`

Comment: What is the language that you are using or regex engine?

Comment: When you ask questions about regular expressions, it's extremely important to identify which regex dialect you're using, as the features and syntax they support vary considerably and frequently there is no "one size fits all" type answer. Identifying the one you're using avoids wasting the time of people who answer with expressions that aren't supported in your chosen dialect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character classes (`[]`) do not make use of `|` to mean `or`; they automatically `or` everything.  You also don't have to escape the single quote (unless of course you're enclosing this whole expression in single quotes).  You want:

```
["' ]?([^"' ]*)["' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a tool or language that supports backreferences, you should be able to use the following:

```
width=("|'|)(\S*)\1
```

This will try to match a single quote, double quote, or empty string with the first capture group, and then the `\1` at the end will be whatever the first group captured.  The value will always be the contents from the second capture group.

I also changed the `[^"]*` to `\S*` so this will match any number of non-whitespace characters.  This is necessary to make sure that your match doesn't just go to the end of the string when there is no quotes around the value.

Example: http://rubular.com/r/Xg8ageZmgy

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
width\s*=\s*(?:["\']([^"\']*)["\']|\S+)
```

I just added the `\S+` to handle `700` after equal sign as OR condition. Also you do not need to place `|` inside the character class `[]`

`\s*` means optional white spaces(zero or more times).

Comment: thanks but this doesn't return 750 unless it's in quotes

Comment: @keeg Remove the `?:` from the above regex to capture the digit. For the quotes you'll have the value in group1 `"750"` and in group2 `750`

Answer (score 0):

Which regular expression language are you using?  Different languages have different details of syntax, so someone might give you an answer that works in their environment but not in yours.

For example, I copied your expression and tried it on some text in Emacs.  It found a match in this text:

```
width=|750|
```

That's because Emacs regex doesn't use the '|' character to signify "either or" within the '[' and ']' brackets; it interprets it as just one more example of a character that the expression might match.

Also, it looks like your expression doesn't always stop after the 750 in this example:

```
width='750'
```

Instead, if there is a '"' character later in the input, it matches everything from the 750 up to that character.  (It did the same thing with my earlier example in Emacs if there was a '"' later in the input.)

You will also match the 750 in this (note the mismatched quotation marks):

```
width='750"
```

Is that a problem, or is that an acceptable outcome?